# How can I solve the problem with Inline for couple elements

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
.footer h3 {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    display: inline;
}

.footermenu nav {
    display: inline;

}
</style>
<body>
<footer class="footer">
    <h3>&copy; ALL RIGHTS RESERVED </h3>
    <nav class="footermenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MORE ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
</body>
```

community! I'm doing basic training on WebDev and ran into a problem with inline positioning.

I created a footer with H3 and nav (`ul>li*2`). I want H3 to be positioned on the left and li anywhere, but on the same line as H3, in principle (haven't questioned the position relative to the center of the page yet).

Solved the problem through display: inline;, but for each element, but could not find a more elegant solution and without duplication

```
.class footer { 
    display: inline;
}

.class h3 {
    display: inline;
}
```

and so on.

Please help me find a competent and elegant solution. Thank you!

```
<footer class="footer">
    <h3>&copy; ALL RIGHTS RESERVED </h3>
    <nav class="footermenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MORE ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>

.footer h3 {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    display: inline;
}

.footermenu nav {
    display: inline;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you draw and upload a picture of your idea? I don't know what is the result which you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, added to your request :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use flex in order to set the position of elements

```
footer {display: flex;}
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, haven't gotten to flex yet in training and tried to figure it out through display. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  .footer h3 {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 15px 30px;
  }
  
  ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  a {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <footer class="footer" style="display: flex">
    <h3>&copy; ALL RIGHTS RESERVED </h3>
    <nav class="footermenu">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MORE ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </footer>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said @KristiK, `flex` is a good way.

But you have a wrong.
`.footermenu nav` doesn't have sense in your code. It points to `nav` elements inside `.footermenu`. So these are appropriate selectors for styling to `nav` in your code:

`nav` or `.footermenu` or `nav.footermenu`.